# Java MongoDB how to use BasicDBList as $in parameter

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have a MongoDB Collection like this, containing details of game players:

```
{
    ...
    "fields" : {
            "playername" : "Koala",
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And I want to get the IDs of the players in an array. So, for example, I do this:

```
// players: ["Koala", "Cactus"]
Criteria base = Criteria.where("fields.playername").in(players);
DBObject match = base.getCriteriaObject();
List<?> userDetailIds = playersCollection.distinct("_id", match);
```

Great, I have a list (`com.mongodb.BasicDBList`) of `ObjectId` objects (`org.bson.types.ObjectId`).
But now I want to use that list in a new `$in` query, for example, get all the badges of those players. The Badges Collection:

```
{
        "badgeName": "MongoDB Killer", 
        "userDetailID" : "525c4be1975ac2a8f4a64c6f"
        ...
}
```

In Java:

```
mongo.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("userDetailID").in(userDetailIds)), Badges.class);
```

This doesn't work, because `userDetailIds` contains `ObjectId` objects and `userDetailID` is a `String` field.
How can I use the BasicDBList as `$in` parameter?
OR:
Can I get an array of `String` IDs instead of `ObjectId`s?

Thanks!

PD. I don't want to iterate over the list to convert it to a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`toHexString()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toHexString--)** method which converts the `ObjectId` instance into a 24-byte hexadecimal string representation:

```
List<ObjectId> objIds = playersCollection.distinct("_id", match);
List<String> userDetailIds = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ObjectId objId : objIds) {
    userDetailIds.add(objId != null ? objId.toHexString() : null);
}

mongo.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("userDetailID").in(userDetailIds)), Badges.class);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But I'm looking for a solution that does not need to iterate over `objIds`. Can I get a `List<String>` instead of `List<ObjectId>`? Is there a way to use `objIds` directly in the second query?